# Add animation clips to the Animation component

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In unity in the Animation component there is the array of Animations. I need to be able to set the elements of that array from a script. How would I go about doing this. I found nothing of help in the scripting API for the Animation. Is this even possible?

Comment: I can´t find any `Animations` field in the [Animation API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animation.html). Do you mean [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animation.Index_operator.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the default animation clip, the [`Animation.clip`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animation-clip.html) property is used.

[image]

To add animation clips, the [`Animation.AddClip`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animation.AddClip.html) function is used.

[image]

Example for both:

```
public AnimationClip clip;
public Animation anim;

void Start()
{
    anim.clip = clip;

    anim.AddClip(clip, "Jump");
    anim.AddClip(clip, "Run");
}
```

> I need to be able to set the elements of that array from a script. How
>   would I go about doing this.

I think that are looking for `AddClip` above. *Note that you'll need to [mark the animation clip as **Legacy**](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Animations.html). If you don't do this, the `AddClip` will give you warning messages and will not add the animation to the array.*

Comment: You can also set the legacy from code with `clip.legacy = true;`

Comment: I though addClip created a new clip. Thanks